# “Parent Role id ‘G7’ does not exist” error message is displayed on login as admin

Tags: php, magento

On login to backend as admin in magento

"Parent Role id 'G7' does not exist" error message is displayed on login as admin

Can any one tell me what to do for this error.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by updating the tree_level on all Users to "2" in the database.

```
UPDATE admin_role SET tree_level = 2 WHERE role_type = "U";
```

Then I cleared my Magento cache and sessions and was able to log in successfully.